C++ declare pure virtual template function must support certain types
Lets say I declare a pure virtual method called readPrimitive
template<class T> void readPrimitive(string data, T& out) = 0;

And I want to specify that derived classes who give this method an implementation MUST support a handful specific types (in my example, all primitive types such as short, long etc.)
How do I do that?

Virtual functions can't be templates.

Method templates cannot be virtual. See: C++ Virtual template method. You can add pure virtual methods for the specific types you need (short, long etc).

As a set of non-template overloads of those specific types:
virtual void readPrimitive(string data, int& out) = 0;
virtual void readPrimitive(string data, float& out) = 0;
virtual void readPrimitive(string data, string& out) = 0;

Virtual functions cannot be templates anyway.

Oh I didn't know virtual functions cannot be templates, whoops. The specific overload approach is what we already have in our codebase, and a coworker suggested changing it to templates. Good to know. Thanks!
